# AngularJS Unit Test: How to write unit test for a scope function?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-runner

new to angular and unit testing, I have a function in my controller as following:

```
function TermList($scope, $http, $q, $timeout, $modal, uiGridConstants, uiGridGroupingConstants, storedValue, sendEmail, getUser) {


    $scope.greeting = "hello";
    $scope.sum = function sum() {
        $scope.z = $scope.x + $scope.y;
    };

    $scope.password = '';
    $scope.grade = function () {
        var size = $scope.password.length;
        if (size > 8) {
            $scope.strength = 'strong';
        } else if (size > 3) {
            $scope.strength = 'medium';
        } else {
            $scope.strength = 'weak';
        }
    };

}
```

and I need to write unit for my scope functions, I have following test case written:

```
describe('routerApp', function () {
    var scope,
    controller;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('routerApp');
    });

    describe('TermList', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('TermList', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));

        it('sets the name', function () {
            expect(scope.greeting).toEqual('hello');
        });
    });
});
```

and I get the following error when I run my unit test:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'greeting' of undefined
```

Comment: What does your `.controller('TermList'...` call look like? Apparently it's not getting building your scope correctly, and it could be something about that.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a lot of dependencies. Is your `controller` variable actually defined? `expect(controller).toBeDefined();` My guess is it's not. You will probably want to create a mocked implementation of all of the controllers dependencies in order to define `controller`. `.controller('TermList', { $scope })` isn't a controller in your project.

Answer (score -1):

Your `inject` parameters look suspect; I'm not entirely convinced that they'd inject anything.

If you want to preserve the name of the parameter, then you can prefix and suffix each parameter with underscores instead.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    controller = _$controller_('TermList', {
        '$scope': scope
    });
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I still get the same error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'greeting' of undefined :(